# Java - Map<String, Set<String>> - how to make intelliJ debug panel print toString() of Map values

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Have a map:

```
        Map<String, Set<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("asdf", new HashSet<>(List.of("a", "b", "c")));
```

IntelliJ’s debug panel prints an entry of this map as just:

> HashSet@1008 size=1

but I want it to print something like:

> “a, b, c”
> // the join of the HashSet.  Other meta info included is fine.

How to do this? I’m ok to make a new class that extends HashSet just to make this work. I prefer not to do this, though.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java | Enable 'toString()' object view enabled? I [can't reproduce problem](https://i.imgur.com/8JQyLDM.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks! Yes, I do have it.  I put some pseudo code above to make the issue clear, but here is what I see:  https://imgur.com/a/GWa8AB0

Comment: What do you expect to see?  You have a Map of String -> Set<String>.  If you want to see it a different way you'll need to wrap this into a class and override toString

Comment: @AmirAfghani Thank you. Yes, I had attempted to override Set<String> toString by wrapping it with a small simple class. However, class MyWrapper extends HashSet<String> { @ Override toString() {return super.toString(); }  }   doesn’t return the comma-join of the Hashset<String> elements.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/04/type-renderers/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugger-data-type-renderers.html . If you don't want to modify toString in your code, you can define custom type renderers to display collections the way you like.

Comment: You aren't actually writing a custom toString by just calling super.toString.... You need to return the "".join(...) code.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for kind response. Yes, I will definitely check that out. Incidentally, do you know why my thing doesn’t produce the results such as you were reproducing?  I mean, you were doing it for the simplified pseudo-code I put above, but I don’t see how my actual Map<SomeOtherObj, Set<String>> isn’t able to do the same.

Comment: @AmirAfghani The problem I have is that I would need access to the private field backing the Set collection if I extend HashSet<String> directly.  If I wrap it using Object composition (ie, as a private field in a wrapper class without extending HashSet<String>), then I would be able to call “” + String.join(mySetThatsWrapped)

Comment: Does it help if you disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java | Enable alternative view for Collections classes?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you. Unfortunately, no. It’s even worse now :)  See:  https://imgur.com/a/wb1njOw

Comment: Thank you both for kind suggestions. I ended up going with the object-wrapper and it works now. When I want to optimize I can just unwrap it by refactoring the SetWrapper back into Set.